# select any 2 of multiple inputs

Tags: digital-logic, multiplexer, parallel

I am trying to input **any** two of six sensor outputs to a microcontroller that has only two compatible ports.

My first idea was to use two 74hc4051 8:1 MUX IC's but it would require 3+3=6 selection pins.

[image]

However, since I am trying to select any two of six, there are 30 possibilities and therefore 5 selection pins should suffice (logically).

Is using two 74hc4051 kind of "in parallel" ok? Is there a way to solve this problem with only using 5 selection pins?

Thank you.

Comment: You should try to find a dual 8-input multiplexer like the following: http://www.e2v.com/shared/content/resources/File/documents/QP_semi/NSC_100363.pdf

Comment: Just wondering, how would you go about using two 74hc4051 in parallel?  Can you put up a schematic?

Comment: You could use a small PROM to convert a 4-bit code to the 6 bits needed by the muxes, but is it really worth it? If you're really hard up for GPIO pins, use a '595 shift register as an I/O expander -- it only needs 3 pins to produce 8 outputs.

Comment: @12Lapointep: Are you aware that the 100363 is an ECL circuit? Not very compatible with microcontrollers.

Comment: @12Lapointep: Thanks. On second thought, I don't know if it is proper to call this "parallel", but I added a brief figure :)

Comment: @Dave Tweed: Thanks Dave. Actually, I am not hard up for GPIO pins. I have only two "dedicated" pins that I can use for my purpose on the microcontroller. Since I need to use no more than 2 of them, I thought this was a valid solution.

Comment: If you are not hard on gpios use the circuit you depicted, with 6 selection pins.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Is it electrically OK? I mean forking an input to two IC's... I will use it if is :)

Comment: It is definitely ok and widely used. Go for it! And make sure to choose proper switching ICs, suitable for your sensors signals.

Comment: You need the full six bits because you also get to pick the order of the outputs, i.e. you can choose to connect in0 to out0 and in1 to out1, or in0 to out1 and in1 to out0. This doubles the possibilities, thus you need an additional bit.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: Thanks, I shall use it. As a tiny note, if I were short on GPIO pins, I might have tried [MAX349](https://datasheets.maximintegrated.com/en/ds/MAX349-MAX350.pdf), which seems to be a very flexible solution.

Comment: @VladimirCravero: BTW, since my inputs are QEI around 20kHz (which happen to be square waves of 5V amplitude), I think 4051's shall do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Some ways to address this problem:

Get a bigger microcontroller.

Use the micro you do have more intelligently.  You apparently have a total of 7 connections to the micro available, since you say that two inputs and 5 select outputs would work.

Just connect the 6 signals directly to 6 micro pins, then do whatever selection you want to perform in firmware.  Very likely the 5 output pins you would use for picking the selection can be configured as digital inputs.

Step back and think about this at a higher level.  Consider what you are really trying to accomplish, without assuming a particular way of accomplishing it.  Your question smells strongly of being about the details of a particular way to addressing the problem, when the right solution is to address the problem in a different way in the first place.

To actually answer this (rather contrived) question, you have 30 possible mux configurations, so it is possible to encode those in 5 bits.  However, decoding from the 5 bits to the 6 separate mux control lines might be more complicated than you are willing to do.

In the arbitrary case, this can be done with a lookup table (memory) that has at least 5 address lines and 6-bit words.  Now you have the additional problem of getting the data into this memory somehow.

Another option is to multiplex the 6 bits into the two muxes.  You could do this with a 3-bit data bus and two separate clock lines for latching the data bus value in front of each of the mux select inputs.

It may also be possible to find muxes with a serial interface like SPI and IIC, but I haven't looked and have never used such chips.

The 6 mux control lines could come from a shift register with a output latch.  That would only require 3 data lines from the micro: Data, Clock, and Latch.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to feed the select inputs of a 8-to-1 mux with 3 select lines.

Then use a 3-bit adder with carry-in set to 1 and feed it with the original 3 select lines adding them to another 2 select lines. Feed the adder outputs to a second 8-to-1 mux.

Now you can route through any two inputs with 5 select bits.

Answer (score 0):

Actually imho the number of valid combinations works out to 6x6 = 36, if the conditions are that **ANY 2** of 6. This includes duplicates - hence the extra 6 over your 30.

However if the constraint of double's and of "reverse pair's" is eliminated, then there are actually only 15 unique combinations. Just some food for thought.

Also, it would be useful to know what these signals are, and how they are being used. Based on this some entirely (i.e. simplified) method might be discovered.

And lastly - if none of the above is valid, then the solution's proposed by Dave Tweed (shifter's) is probably the simplist.